# Redirect HTTP > HTTPS when port is always 80

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, https, url-rewriting

Our application needs to redirect `HTTP` requests to `HTTPS`. 
Normally i would use the `RewriteCond` as below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

The thing with our current hosting company is that the requested port is always 80. It doens't matter if we send a `HTTP` or `HTTPS` request, the `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` is always 80.

We can handle this in `PHP`, but we also want to force files to `HTTPS`.

So the concrete question. Is there anyway to force `HTTPS` in `.htaccess` without using `RewriteCond` like `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` or `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}`.

Comment: Are you behind an SSL terminating proxy…? Does that proxy send any indicative HTTP header informing you of the protocol used…?

Comment: You have specified the condition, but not the rule that applies to that condition.

Comment: @deceze really good question. I think that is probably our problem. I think the server is behind a proxy. The only difference i can find in the `HTTP` response is that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']` is different. A `HTTPS` request adds the value `br`. But I have no idea what that means and if that has something to do with it.

Comment: You should check with your host how to detect HTTPS. Unless the proxy forwards that information, or leaves other specific traces, this is not really doable.

Comment: @S.Pols: Does `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off` work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Your situation is not that uncommon. Try this ([X-Forwarded-Proto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields) is de facto standard for identifying the originating protocol of an HTTP request):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this also triggers an infinity loop.

Comment: im using cloudflare is that why the other solutions didn't work?

Comment: Yes, this is necessary in cases when ssl/tls is not terminated on webserver but on intermediate reverse proxy (or load balancer or CDN)